# Getting precise column in Query result with Code Igniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter, row

I am looking for a way to return the value of a precise column in the first result of a query.

The query result contains always 1 row containing the following columns :

> ID
>   PW
>   RANK

I am trying to only get the rank value in order to push it into a session variable.

I tried messing with :

```
$row-> $query->row();
```

But then I don't know how to get only the value of the rank column. Ideally, I would want to get that value, then return it to allow my controller to set it in the session variable ( doing it in the model would be easier but would break the MVC pattern, right ?)

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the controller call a function in the model that return that value. Let's say the model has a function name `get_rank()`

```
public function get_rank($id)
{
  // assumes your ID is an int
  $id = (int)$id;

  // avoid wasting a query
  if ($id < 1) return FALSE;

  // build query
  $this->db->select('rank');
  $this->db->from('YOUR_TABLE');
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  // maybe some sorting / limiting here if you need it

  // get result
  $rs = $this->db->get();

  if ($rs->num_rows() > 0)
  {
    // just get the first row
    $row = $rs->row();
    return $row->rank;
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```